# Scope on Object not Behaving as Expected

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to clean up a long-standing bad habit in coding:  Writing widgets to the global scope.

I've made a large, mostly self-contained script for a news roll on a webpage and was pleasantly surprised at how well it worked after I stuffed the whole thing into a function... TOO well in fact.

To ensure I wasn't cheating, I wrote the following code to make sure my scoping was correct:

```
var story_count = "THIS IS NOT A NUMBER";

console.log(story_count);

touch_roll = function()
{
    this.story_count = 0;
}

console.log(story_count);

touch_roll();

console.log(story_count);
```

Fully expecting this to yield the following response in the console

```
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
```

I was entirely surprised to find the output was, in fact, **this**:

```
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
0
```

Is `this` not what I think it is?  Research hasn't really helped, but I'm a little burnt out so it's entirely possible I'm reading it all wrong.  If not this, then how DO I keep all of my namespaces completely within the scope of that function so as not to mess with existing bits on the site?

---

As per Matt's answer below, here is the corrected code:

```
var story_count = "THIS IS NOT A NUMBER";

console.log(story_count);

var touch_roll = new function()
{
    this.story_count = 0;
    console.log(story_count);
}

console.log(story_count);
```

By declaring `touch_roll` as a `var` and instantiating the function as `new` Javascript evaluates said function into an object as run-time (so we can also remove the call to `touch_roll()` at the bottom).

The corrected output is as follows:

```
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
0
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not invoking `touch_roll` with `new`, `this` is the `window` object (which is what global variables in browser environments belong to).

If you were to use `new`, then you'd get:

```
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
THIS IS NOT A NUMBER
```

Additionally, you're declaring `touch_roll` as a implicit global variable. Either use [function declaration syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), or add a `var` to it.

Comment: So `var touch_roll = new function()` ?

Comment: It's making me wait to accept the answer, I'll modify my question with the corrected code and check box you after lunch!